# 2 codes work, the third doesn't

Tags: python

Beginner here. :)

So I want to achieve is this:

User enters a number. It spits out the ^3 of the number. If user enters a letter instead, it prints out a error message.

Code #1 works great:

```
def thirdpower():
try:
    number = int(raw_input("Enter a number : "))
    n=number**3
    print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" % (number,n)
except ValueError:
    print "You must enter an integer, please try again."
    thirdpower()

thirdpower()
```

But I want to try doing the same thing with a `while` statement since I want to practice with it. I know its a bit more verbose this way, but I think it's good practice nonetheless.

```
number=raw_input("Please Enter an integer")
while number.isalpha():
    print "You have entered letter. Please try again"
    number=raw_input("Please Enter an integer")

n=int(number)**3
print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" %(int(number), n)
```

My question is this. If I remove the `number=raw_input("Please Enter an integer")` under the `while` statement and replace it with a `break`, the code doesn't work.

Here is what I mean:

```
number=raw_input("Please Enter an integer")
while number.isalpha():
    print "You have entered letter. Please try again"
    break #This break here ruins everything :(

n=int(number)**3
print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" %(int(number), n)
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` statement jumps out of a loop.

In this case, if the user types in a letter, the loop runs the `print` statement, then immediately reaches the `break` and terminates instead of looping over and over.  (`break` is more useful when you put it inside an if statement that the program doesn't always reach.)

But using `break` doesn't stop the rest of your program from running, so Python still tries to run line 6. Since the `number` variable contains a letter, the program crashes when it tries to convert it to a number.

You were probably trying to end the program if the user typed in a letter.  In that case, you could use the built-in `sys` module to do something like this:

```
import sys

number=raw_input("Please Enter an integer")
if number.isalpha():
    print "You have entered letter. Please try again"
    sys.exit()
#...
```

Comment: If that is the case, shouldn't it at least print out a `You have entered letter. Please try again` and then terminate?

Comment: @user3386440 You're right, the `print` statement runs once before the loop breaks. I edited the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

The `break` exits out of the `while` loop, at which point `number` is still whatever letter was entered so you get an error trying to make it an `int`.